# Xamarin Live Reload Error

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting the following error when trying to make the Live Reload work. What could be the cause?

**Extension version: 0.3.27**

**Nuget package version: 0.3.27** [Installed only in the .netstandard library]

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Live.Reload, Version=0.3.27.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'Xamarin.Live.Reload.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)   XamarinTest.Droid
```

Comment: Have you tried to restore the nuget package?

Comment: I did try everything. Deleting the packages folder, reinstalling. Nothing works

Comment: Same problem.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. Didn't find any solution so far.

Comment: Alternatively, you can take a look at this https://www.twitch.tv/videos/441875218

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/live-reload

> Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load assembly 'Xamarin.Live.Reload, Version=0.3.27.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='.  The host project should be using
>   PackageReference instead of packages.config